# How Can I Use DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder to a Hex delimiter?

Tags: netty, delimiter

I'm looking for a way to use the delimiter "dhav" to form frames from network data with DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder class.

After receiving this frame I need to implement logic to extract data from a pre-defined layout.

The problem is that I still do not understand how this decoder handlers relationship works.

The steps are: 
1 Assemble the frames (dhav delimiter)
2 Extract specific data from these frames

Could help me implement at least the initial steps?

Answer (score 1):

The DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder will only "split" your frames and forward them to the next handler in your pipeline. You will need to extract the data itself in another handler which you place behind the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.